# Alternative framework to Google map API which is "offline"

Tags: google-maps, maps

I need to develop a feature where I need to show the directions between two zipcodes on a map offline. Is there any such framework which can display directions between two zipcodes ? I tried Highmaps, but it doesn't show directions between tow point. I looked at the below apis too. But I think they cannot work offline. Thanks in advance

MapTiler Cloud: https://cloud.maptiler.com/

Microsoft Maps API: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx

MapQuest: http://developer.mapquest.com/

(provided by TuxGeek)

Mapjam: http://mapjam.com

OpenStreetMap API: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Osmdroid: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmdroid

OpenStreetMap Android http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

(provided by AGrunewald)

GraphHopper Directions and Matrix API https://graphhopper.com/#directions-api

(provided by karussell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GrapHopper API that you mention is based on their SDK:

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper

and it allows to perform routing in offline mode, in Java, and, more in particular, in Android.

There's a sub-project where GrapHopper is integrated with Mapsforge (library for rendering OpenStreeMap data offline) for Android:

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/0.8/android

Comment: Hi , This is for android phone only? or I can use for any webbased application on a desktop

Comment: Yes, it also runs server side. It's both a library and a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting your own open-source instance, for example Graphhopper.